# Замена текста картинками

Tags: html, php

Возможно - ли сделать замену текста - картинками? В тексте только цифры. И у меня есть картинки этих самых цифр. И при этом, чтобы код читал это как текст. Ибо у меня с этим текстом таймер. Не понимаю.

Comment: ничего не понял.

Comment: > И днём, и ночью код учёный всё ходит по цепи кругом.

код читать не  умеет, в общем: 

@Maykop, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: Мне кажется автор имел ввиду что то подобное: http://habrahabr.ru/post/61033/

Comment: Все вы были новичками. Я, как и любой новичок не сделал ничего. Потому что не знаю, за что уцепиться. Я и прошу помощи.

Comment: @Maykop, новички тоже делятся на две категории: те, кто может внятно объяснить суть проблемы и те, кто своими вопросами, вынуждают чесать затылок в догадках.

Comment: Копать надо в сторону SVG.

Answer (score 2):

Вариант 1: [создаём](http://we.easyelectronics.ru/CADSoft/fastfont---samopisnaya-risovalka-rastrovyh-shriftov.html) или [находим](http://www.google.com/fonts/?subset=greek&sort=var) [в сети](http://ru.fonts2u.com/category.html?id=14) подходящий шрифт, выводим цифры таймера этим шрифтом. Примеры есть по третьей ссылке.

Вариант 2: на сервере средствами PHP в строке с временем таймера [заменяем](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-replace.php) цифры и прочие нужные символы на теги [`img`](http://htmlbook.ru/html/img) с нужным атрибутом `src`.

Вариант 3: на клиенте средствами JavaScript в [контенте](http://innerhtml.ru/) [элемента](http://javascript.ru/tutorial/dom/search) со строкой таймера [заменяем](http://javascript.ru/String/replace) цифры и прочие нужные символы на теги [`img`](http://htmlbook.ru/html/img) с нужным атрибутом `src`.

Comment: @fori1ton, сразу видно - фрилансер: телепатия зашкаливает... )

Comment: @Равнодушный вы так говорите, как будто в этом что то плохое :3

Comment: Господа, где взяли телепатМод?

Comment: aptitude install libtelepathy2

Comment: [libastral][1] же

  [1]: http://lurkmore.to/Libastral

Comment: такой нет, а libthelepathy2 есть

    apt-cache policy libastral
    N: Не удалось найти пакет libastral

Comment: Его нет в стандартном репозитории. Нужен сторонний PPA, например, этот: https://launchpad.net/~sbasalaev/+archive/pub

Comment: у меня debian :)

Comment: Жаль) Я бы предложил собрать из исходников, но http://libastral.so/ лежит, на SourceForge они исходников не держали, а больше я нигде их найти не могу.

Comment: А, не, вот есть исходники: http://sourceforge.net/projects/libastralso/